# Can I mount host directory contents to container directory?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

Here's a part of my dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /home/node/project
WORKDIR /home/node/project
ADD ./src/static/package.json /home/node/project
RUN npm install
```

Then in docker-compose I have something like this:

```
volumes:
  - ../../src/static/:/home/node/project/
```

The idea is to mount all host directory contents to project directory.
And it works! But when I tried to run docker-compose on other machine, host folder overlaid container folder.

So I wondering, is it legal operation?

Comment: Host folder is supposed to overlay container folder. From documentation:  If the path /opt/webapp already exists inside the container’s image, the /src/webapp mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content. Once the mount is removed, the content is accessible again. This is consistent with the expected behavior of the mount command. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

Comment: I wonder if there is a problem with the parameter of the option `--volume`. The documentation (cf `man docker run`) specifies:

`The  CONTAINER-DIR must be an absolute path such as /src/docs.`

Comment: Yes, I know about overlaying. The problem is, it doesn't work in my situation. In project directory I have host files, node_modules and package.json.